# How can I set padding left in my template that works both for Outlook & Gmail Emails?

Tags: css, email, html-email

I set a padding left of 15 pixels in my code in my list element, the padding shown does not look the same in the two platforms.

```
<ul style="padding-left: 10px !important; margin: 0 !important;">
    <li
       style="text-align: left !important; font-size: 14px; font-family: bold, sans-serif, sans-serif !important;">
       <span
          style="color: #055151; line-height: 150%; font-family: bold, sans-serif;">List element</span>
    </li>
 </ul>
```

How to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The Outlooks* on Windows use Word as a rendering engine for HTML and CSS. I see two things that could be problematic here:

- Inline `!important` styles are not supported.
- Word uses `text-indent` to actually position the list item marker. In order to avoid impacting other email clients, we can use `mso-text-indent-alt` that will apply specifically to *the Outlooks* using Word's rendering engine.

Here’s an example code that should match what you want to achieve:

```html
<ul style="padding:0; margin:0 0 0 10px;">
    <li style="mso-text-indent-alt:-0.75em; text-align:left; font:bold 14px sans-serif;">
        <span style="color:#055151; line-height:150%;">List element</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And here are [test screenshots on Email on Acid](https://app.emailonacid.com/app/acidtest/J9Wyx7CBrHJwPpvz6LdaII1BJgvoIzTiijLXagOccHctg/list).